# Existence Exception in Prolog Program

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a rule in my prolog program that determines if someone is the brother of someone else.

For example, if I type brother_of(chris, X) it will return christy because chris is the brother of christy. However, when I type this I get an existence exception. I've included facts to cover everything, but maybe it's a problem in my rule definition? The code is below.

```
/* Facts */
female(ella).
female(jodi). 
female(sonya).
female(jane). 
female(christy). 
female(mary).
male(arnold).
male(chris).
male(louis).
male(mark).  
father(arnold).
father(louis).
father(mark).
mother(ella).
mother(jodi).
mother(jane).
mother(mary).
father_of(arnold, chris). /* arnold is the father of chris */
father_of(arnold, christy).
father_of(louis, mark).
father_of(mark, arnold). 
mother_of(mary, chris).
mother_of(mary, christy).          
mother_of(jane, arnold).    
mother_of(ella, sonya).
mother_of(jodi, ella).
mother_of(jodi, mark).

/* Rules */

brother_of(X, Y) :-
    male(X),
    ((father_of(Z, X), father_of(Z, Y));
    (mother_of(W, X), mother_of(W, Y))),
    X =\= Y.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `=\=` is used in arithmetic only (AFAIK), to see if two terms are different (non-unifiable) use the operator `\=`:

```
X \= Y.
```

**Update:** a brief introduction to the [cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28logic_programming%29) (`!`) goal: when the cut is used in a predicate, it means no more answers should be searched besides the already found ones (i.e. you are "cutting the remaining branches" in the search tree). Example:

```
first_child(X,Y) :-
    father_of(X,Y), !.

?- first_child(arnold,Y).

Y = chris ;

no
```

After the cut is reached, all choice points **before** the cut are discarded (but new ones can be created after it). In you example, you know that if X and Y have the same father, it's irrelevant if they also have the same mother. So you can place the cut right after the "common father" part succeeds:

```
brother_of(X, Y) :-
    male(X),
    ((father_of(Z, X), father_of(Z, Y), X \= Y, !); # If cut is reached, will not run the next line
    (mother_of(W, X), mother_of(W, Y), X \= Y)).
```

Note however that using cut has many pitfalls (refer to "green cut" vs "red cut" in the linked Wikipedia article), but it's too much to describe here. (note how I repeated `X \= Y` - if I didn't do that the program would fail sometimes)

Lastly, I'd also like to point out that using `;` is often discouraged when writing Prolog code (you can use when needed though). Instead, write it in two clauses:

```
brother_of(X, Y) :-
    male(X),
    father_of(Z, X),
    father_of(Z, Y), 
    X \= Y,
    !.
brother_of(X, Y) :-
    male(X),
    mother_of(W, X),
    mother_of(W, Y), 
    X \= Y.
```

(this `;` vs two clauses is a bit subjective, though, so I won't argue too much about it... just know that both ways are possible, and will produce the same result)

Comment: That worked, thank you! But now when I ask brother_of(chris, X) it returns christy twice. After the first time christy is returned, I type ";" to make sure there isn't any more, which there shouldn't be so it should return "no" but it returns christy again. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: You need the [cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28logic_programming%29) goal: `!`. Ask me if you need help on how to use it (dunno if you already saw it in your studies it or not)

Comment: I haven't seen it actually. How do I use it?

Comment: @aclark didn't see your comment, was writing a response... :) anyway, I hope it helps!

Comment: That explains it much better though. I was just kind of guessing before and it worked out. So this is great thanks!

Comment: Using !/0 is unfortunate here because it eleminates valid solutions for example in the query ?- brother_of(X, Y). Instead of (\=)/2, you can use dif/2, which also works when either or both of its arguments are variables and is thus much easier to understand and use.

Comment: @mat true, that's why I said cut had many pitfalls, unfortunatly I wasn't able to elaborate further (I guess the answer would get too long). Very nice this `dif/2`, didn't know about it! I'll take a closer look at it as soon as I have time, but I can already see that it's really a better fit to the problem at hand than cut. (P.S. do you know if it's supported in most prologs? a quick google search only showed references to it in swi)

Comment: dif/2 is supported in all serious Prolog systems, including SICStus, Yap and SWI.